# Where should bundle install be executed?

Tags: ruby, deployment, build, rubygems, bundler

I'm running a build server (Jenkins) for my continuous delivery pipeline.

To ensure that my systems run the same version of the software, I'm separating the [build step from the release/run step](https://12factor.net/build-release-run). So the build server is creating a package that is being distributed to the servers running the package.

I'm now unsure whether the `bundle install --deployment` step is part of the build step (so it creates a vendor/ directory that is part of the distribution package) or whether it is part of the release step (being executed on the target system).

Whats the best practice in the Ruby world here?

Comment: It depends if you're building in a container where you will ship the binary image, or if you're building for a server deployment where the target OS might differ substantially.

Comment: It's not a container. But both systems use the same operation systems and only use packages for any dependency or library.

Comment: I prefer to do the final install on the target system just to be sure, but if you're confident you could package up the whole thing, do that as part of a build step, and dump it on the target server.